Why is my terminal on VSCode recognizing flutter command but my Terminal isn't? And why is one VScode instance recognizing it but another one isn't?
Image showing issue 
I've been working on a project with flutter pretty much all of yesterday, running commands, flutter doctor, messing around the android sdk to make it work on my Ubuntu device (because it was working fine on my Windows but I struggled to work with it on Ubuntu), but now my terminal is not recognizing flutter, but the terminal inside VSCode is, even when on the same directory as my terminal.
I installed flutter via the plugin in VScode so I don't know where the installation is.
My professor sent us a flutter project file but the imports were all broken and I couldn't figure out why, so I opened the terminal on VScode to do flutter clean and flutter pub get to see if it'd do the trick, but all of a sudden the flutter command was not being recognized.
I hopped on another project that I was working yesterday and performing flutter commands, and to my surprise, it works there.

you need to set-up environment for flutter.https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/mobile?tab=download#update-your-windows-path-variable   follow this!

From your screenshot, I would conclude that the PATH is set up differently, or that some shell function or aliases are set up differently. As a first check, I would compare the output of echo $PATH and echo $- in both terminals.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
